# Arrange a single column data in multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table(raw data). I would like to see the data in following format(Formatted Data).

I tried the following query. It produces a rather weird result. Could someone guide me here how to achieve this.

```
declare @monthnames varchar(100)

    select distinct [Month], MonthNumber
    into #Months 
    from Table
    order by MonthNumber

SELECT @monthnames =   Stuff((SELECT ', ' + [Month]
    FROM #Months
    order by MonthNumber
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')

declare @query varchar(500)

set @query = 'select CUR,' + @monthnames +
            ' from ' + 
            ' Pivot ( min(DATE) for [Month] in (' + @monthnames + ') ) as Pivottable ORDER BY CUR' 

EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: Can you add your raw data as text please (or to a fiddle)

Comment: what is `#Temp` ?

Comment: If you search for "Unpivot" you'll find many solutions to this. If you can't get a solution to work you need to be far more specific than "weird result". You need to do some analysis

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I did search. i wold have posted the result unless it was too big and occupied. If you could execute the query with sample data, you will understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to use `Dynamic SQL` as you have a fixed number of pivoting columns.

What you are missing is the `rn`, so that each date appear under different row

```
SELECT  CUR, 
        [1] as Jan,
        [2] as Feb,
        [3] as Mar,
        [4] as Apr,
        [5] as May
FROM    (
            SELECT  CUR, MonthNumber, DATE, 
                    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUR, MonthNumber ORDER BY DATE)
            FROM    #Table
         ) AS d
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(DATE)
            FOR MonthNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
        ) AS p
```

Comment: @AnonymusUser , just run the inner query and you will see that the `rn` increments for each date under same `CUR` and `MonthNumber`. You need another unique value so that when you `PIVOT` it appear as different rows

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
CUR varchar(10),
[Month] varchar(20),
MonthNumber tinyint,
[Date] date
);

insert into @t(Cur, [Month], MonthNumber, [Date])
values
('AED', 'January', 1, '20200110'),
('AED', 'February', 2, '20200212'),('AED', 'February', 2, '20200215'),
('AED', 'March', 3, '20200305'),('AED', 'March', 3, '20200305'),('AED', 'March', 3, '20200305'),
('AED', 'April', 4, '20200402'),('AED', 'April', 4, '20200412'),('AED', 'April', 4, '20200415'),
('AED', 'June', 6, '20200619'),
('AED', 'August', 8, '20200801'),('AED', 'August', 8, '20200805'),('AED', 'August', 8, '20200810'), ('AED', 'August', 8, '20200824'),
----
('ARS', 'January', 1, '20200118'),
('ARS', 'April', 4, '20200416'),
('ARS', 'May', 5, '20200512'), ('ARS', 'May', 5, '20200513'), ('ARS', 'May', 5, '20200514'),
('ARS', 'September', 9, '20200902'),('ARS', 'September', 9, '20200922');


select CUR, [January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December]
from
(
select CUR, [Date], dense_rank() over(partition by CUR, [Month] /*or MonthNumber*/ order by [Date]) as ranking,
    [Month]
from @t
) as t
pivot
(
min([Date]) for [Month] in ([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])
) as pvt
order by CUR;
```

Comment: @Iptr,  This too produced the same result. Could you please explain what's happening after ranking the data by Currency and Month.